# tar: Unrecognized archive format error when trying to unpack flower_photos.tgz, TF tutorials on OSX

Tags: python, macos, curl, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm trying to unpack the flower_photos.tgz after curling it using

```
curl -O http://download.tensorflow.org/example_../images/flower_photos.tgz
tar xzf flower_photos.tgz
```

This is from the image retraining tutorial for TensorFlow

Results from curling

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   127  100   127    0     0    255      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   255
```

Then when I try to unpack

```
tar xzf flower_photos.tgz
tar: Unrecognized archive format
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

Comment: same question here, can you check the new answers in this thread?

Comment: sometimes you think you have downloaded the real archive but you just downloaded a HTML file with some error information, please check the content of your file using commands like more or cat (ie. more flower_photos.tgz) in order to verify whether it is a compressed file or only a regular file with some message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the new instructions on TensorFlow website run without issues

I just tried the instructions posted on [How to Retrain Inception's Final Layer for New Categories](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining)

```
curl -O http://download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz

tar xzf flower_photos.tgz
```

It worked without any problems

Answer (score 13):

try using the `-L` flag, i.e.

```
curl -OL http://download.tensorflow.org/example_../images/flower_photos.tgz
```

source: https://github.com/arq5x/bedtools2/issues/189

Comment: Nice, this works for `.tar.gz` as well!

Answer (score 6):

I solved this problem by downloading the file from safari and then copy the file to your directory. There is something wrong with the file download by command curl. Maybe you can try my method.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem

```
tar: Error opening archive: Unrecognized archive format
```

In my case the actual file didn't exist anymore (checked by putting the link in the browser), so my tar file was actually an error page (probably 404 page).